# Unable to get a class method to work in loops

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS (or coding in general) and I'm experimenting with a few things to learn. I'm playing around with class methods in a loop for no reason other than to screw around and hopefully learn a thing or two, but I'm unable to get the desired result.

Here is the code:

```js
class CD extends Media {
  constructor(title, artist) {
    super(title);
    this._artist = artist;
    this._songTitles = [];
  }
  get songTitles() {
    return this._songTitles;
  }
  addSong(song) {
    if (typeof song === 'string') {
      this._songTitles.push(song)
    } else {
      console.log('You need to input the song title as a string.');
    }
  }
  shuffle() {
  const songList = this.songTitles;
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * songList.length);
  return songList[randomIndex];
  }
};

const flowerBoy = new CD('Flower Boy', 'Tyler, The Creator');
flowerBoy.addSong('Foreword (feat. Rex Orange County)');
flowerBoy.addSong('Where This Flower Blooms (feat. Frank Ocean)');
flowerBoy.addSong('Sometimes...');
flowerBoy.addSong('See You Again (feat. Kali Uchis)');

const songs = flowerBoy.songTitles;
while (flowerBoy.shuffle() != 'Sometimes...') {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);
  console.log(flowerBoy.songTitles[randomIndex]);
};
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a loop that'll continue to shuffle through the `flowerBoy.songTitles` array until it comes across the string `'Sometimes...'`. I think I've managed to achieve the loop part because thee output always shows a different amount of songs, however the loop won't stop at `'Sometimes...'` and at times will stop at a different song.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You're not logging the song that `.shuffle()` returned, you log some random other song - completely independent from the random selection that `.shuffle()` is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you had in your code is that you're not displaying the value that was used in the loop condition as Bergi said.

```
class CD extends Media {
  constructor(title, artist) {
    super(title);
    this._artist = artist;
    this._songTitles = [];
  }
  get songTitles() {
    return this._songTitles;
  }
  addSong(song) {
    if (typeof song === 'string') {
      this._songTitles.push(song)
    } else {
      console.log('You need to input the song title as a string.');
    }
  }
  shuffle() {
    const songList = this.songTitles;
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * songList.length);
    return songList[randomIndex];
  }
};

const flowerBoy = new CD('Flower Boy', 'Tyler, The Creator');
flowerBoy.addSong('Foreword (feat. Rex Orange County)');
flowerBoy.addSong('Where This Flower Blooms (feat. Frank Ocean)');
flowerBoy.addSong('Sometimes...');
flowerBoy.addSong('See You Again (feat. Kali Uchis)');

const songs = flowerBoy.songTitles;
let song = flowerBoy.shuffle();
while (song != 'Sometimes...') {
  console.log(song);
  song = flowerBoy.shuffle();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class CD extends Media {
  constructor(title, artist) {
    super(title);
    this._artist = artist;
    this._songTitles = [];
  }
  get songTitles() {
    return this._songTitles;
  }
  addSong(song) {
    if (typeof song === 'string') {
      this._songTitles.push(song)
    } else {
      console.log('You need to input the song title as a string.');
    }
  }
  shuffle() {
    const songList = this.songTitles;
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * songList.length);

    return songList[randomIndex];
  }
};

const flowerBoy = new CD('Flower Boy', 'Tyler, The Creator');

flowerBoy.addSong('Foreword (feat. Rex Orange County)');
flowerBoy.addSong('Where This Flower Blooms (feat. Frank Ocean)');
flowerBoy.addSong('Sometimes...');
flowerBoy.addSong('See You Again (feat. Kali Uchis)');

const songs = flowerBoy.songTitles;

const shuffleFlowerBoy = () => {
  const song = flowerBoy.shuffle();
  console.log(song);
  if (song !== 'Sometimes...') {
    return shuffleFlowerBoy();
  }
  
  return song;
}

shuffleFlowerBoy();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this code and it will always output ``'Sometimes...'``, without outputting any of the other songs in the array.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what your code was doing. What is it that you want to happen?, otherwise add a console log into to shuffle func - Edited code to reflect